# Unit testing Spring Cloud Stream Producer-Processor-Consumer Scenario

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream

I have created an sample app for producer-processor-consumer scenario using Spring Cloud Scenario. Here, I have used legacy annotation based approach.

In unit tests, I wanted to test simple scenario of producing a message and asserting consumed message after it undergoes transformation. But I am not receiving message at consumer binding end. Please let me know what could be missing here.

**Producer.java**

```
@EnableBinding(MyProcessor.class)
public class Producer {

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = MyProcessor.OUTPUT, poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
    public MessageSource<String> produceMessage() {
        return () -> new GenericMessage<>("Hello Spring Cloud World >>> " + Instant.now());
    }
}
```

**TransformProcessor.java**

```
@EnableBinding(MyProcessor.class)
public class TransformProcessor {

    @Transformer(inputChannel = MyProcessor.OUTPUT, outputChannel = MyProcessor.INPUT)
    public String transform(String message) {
        System.out.println("Transforming the message: " + message);
        return message.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

Consumer.java

```
@EnableBinding(MyProcessor.class)
public class Consumer {

    @StreamListener(MyProcessor.INPUT)
    public void consume(String message) {
        System.out.println("Consuming transformed message: " + message);
    }
}
```

**MyProcessor.java**

```
public interface MyProcessor {
    String INPUT = "my-input";
    final static String OUTPUT = "my-output";

    @Input(INPUT)
    SubscribableChannel anInput();

    @Output(OUTPUT)
    MessageChannel anOutput();
}
```

**SpringCloudStreamLegacyApplicationTests.java**

```
@SpringBootTest
class SpringCloudStreamLegacyApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MyProcessor myProcessor;

    @Autowired
    private MessageCollector messageCollector;

    @Test
    public void testConsumer() {

        myProcessor.anOutput().send(new GenericMessage<byte[]>("hello".getBytes()));

        Message<?> poll = messageCollector.forChannel(myProcessor.anInput()).poll();
        System.out.println("Received: " + poll.getPayload());
    }

}
```

Here, I am expecting a message to be received in *handleMessage* method.

Note, I am using following dependency for tests:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: If you are using the annotation approach, you probably don't want to add the new test binder as a dependency - the one that you mentioned above. You may want to stick with using `spring-cloud-stream-test-support` and its `MessageCollector` mechanism.

Comment: Modified the code accordingly to use `MessageCollector` but getting following exception: `
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Channel [bean 'my-input'] was not bound by class org.springframework.cloud.stream.test.binder.TestSupportBinder

 at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198)`

Comment: Can you create a small sample app with this issue? Then we can take a look.

Comment: @sobychacko I have shared the sample app at https://github.com/Omkar-Shetkar/Spring-Cloud-Stream-Legacy Thanks for your time and support.